# Amazon Elasticsearch Upgrade from 7.7 to 7.9 still processing after 12 hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

Last night I started an upgrade of my Amazon Elasticsearch Cluster from version 7.7 to 7.9. It's now been running for over 12 hours and remains in the `Upgrade Processing` state. It has 12,000 documents which doesn't seem like a lot to me so I'm concerned that it may have become stuck in a partially upgraded state. Any input?

[image]

Comment: @dadoonet, At least, state that you're working for Elasticsearch if you're doing this kind of comment. Trying to provide some help would have been good too

Comment: @dadonet yes appreciate the sales pitch but not super helpful towards solving the problem at hand.

Comment: I would recommend contacting AWS support. They have a bit more observability into what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to answer to a question without logs or details but i will try to guess.
From what i'm seeing in the image, it seems you're lacking free space for the reindexing to continue.

Free storage 7.15 GiB == Minimum free storage space 7.15 GiB

When reindexing data you need at least twice the amount of space taken by the data

But you also need to take into account the fact that Elasticsearch stop writing data when it feels out of free space. The tresholds can be configured with the following properties:

```
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled

cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low

cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high

cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.flood_stage
```

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.12/modules-cluster.html#disk-based-shard-allocation for more details

Comment: Thanks for the info. It doesn't appear that I can cancel this upgrade process, so can I update those settings mid-upgrade process and expect it to kick back into progressing? And I assume I would update those through the ES API? Disclosure I'm quite a basic ES user, so far just limited to streaming in lambda data and viewing it in Kibana.

Comment: The properties are flagged as dynamic so if the rest api is still accessible you can try it, A sample to do it is included in the link i've already provided. But in this half upgraded state i'm not sure. Do you have a backup? restoring a backup would be the better choice. If you don't have any backup and if you still can query elasticsearch, extracting the documents before doing anything would be a safe choice. If nothing else can be done and your data can't be lost, contacting the AWS team is also a good choice because the upgrading process may have done some backup before launching.

Comment: Looks like the server is not queryable in its current state, so I will pursue with AWS Support. Thank you